# Qt Signals and slots - No matching function for call

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I am learning QT and am trying to get my signals and slots working. I am having no luck.
Here is my Main

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);

      FilmInput fi;
      FilmWriter fw;
      QObject::connect (&fi->okButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), &fi, SLOT( okButtonClicked() ) 

    ); //Error received Base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'FilmInput'
     QObject::connect(&fi,SIGNAL(obtainFilmData(QVariant*)),&fw,SLOT(saveFilmData(QVariant*)));
//Error received No matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(Filminput*, const     char*, FilmWriter*, const char*)
      fi.show();
      return app.exec();

    }
```

and here is my sad attempt at signals and slots:

FilmInput.h

```
public:
        FilmInput();
        void okButtonClicked();
    QPushButton* okButton;
signals:
        void obtainFilmData(Film *film);
Here is FilmWriter.h

public slots:
    int saveFilm(Film &f);

Here is Film Input.cpp


void FilmInput::okButtonClicked(){
    Film *aFilm=new Film();
    aFilm->setDirector(this->edtDirector->text());
    emit obtainFilmData(aFilm);

}
```

Here is FilmWriter.cpp

```
void FilmInput::okButtonClicked(){
    Film *aFilm=new Film();
    aFilm->setDirector(this->edtDirector->text());
    emit obtainFilmData(aFilm);

}
```

Please assist me in getting the signals and slots to work, I have spent hours but am no closer to getting it working. I have added the errors received in my comments above.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okButton is already a pointer, then you should remove the ampersand:

```
QObject::connect(fi.okButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &fi, SLOT(okButtonClicked()));
```

(actually, be sure you create the button in FilmInput' constructor...)

Next, your methods signature doesn't match what you say in connect: given your functions, should be

```
Object::connect(&fi, SIGNAL(obtainFilmData(Film*)), &fw, SLOT(saveFilmData(Film*)));
```

this will work, because you are exchanging a pointer, and then Qt can make a copy of it. Otherwise, your type should be registered.

Comment: Still get error. 
..\Main.cpp: In function 'int qMain(int, char**)': 
..\Main.cpp:11: error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(FilmInput*, const char*, FilmWriter*, const char*)' 
c:\Qt\2010.04\qt\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:198: note: candidates are: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) 
c:\Qt\2010.04\qt\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h:313: note: bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const

Comment: Hi, I could not type more in the comment above, but want to say that I tried your solution and it did not change the error message. Thank you

Comment: you should derive both FilmInput and FilmWriter from QObject, and add the Q_OBJECT macro in headers. Then make a rebuild all...

Answer (score 1):

The first error is caused by `&fi->okButton` because `->` has a higher precedence than `&`. See [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Easily fixed with `(&fi)->okButton`.

The second error is likely caused by one or both objects not inheriting from `QObject`. Signals and slots can only work between `QObjects`. Just a quick checklist:

1. Both sender and receiver must inherit from the `QObject` class
2. The `Q_OBJECT` macro must be used in the definition of each class
3. You must generate the appropriate meta-object code and compile it into your project. See [Meta-Object Compiler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/moc.html)

Also, if you're using Qt version 5.0 or higher, you should start passing function pointers to the connect methods instead of using the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. It'll provide compile-time checking of the connections.

Comment: Hi Seth,

Thank you, point 1 has solved that issue. 
I do have Q_OBJECT defined and still get the error, I would not be surprised if I have done my signals and slots completely incorrectly, are you sure they look ok?
I will add meta-object as soon as I have the core functionality working.

Comment: Signals and slots (and many other Qt conveniences) will not function without the meta-object information for those classes compiled into the project. If you're using Qt Creator that's all done for you, but in most other environments you have to generate it yourself. Please follow the directions on [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/moc.html) if you haven't already.