# QML communicating with C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am having problems with QML communicating with C++. I had followed all the steps expected to make the sample code to run properly. After some hours working on this small example, it comes down to one error message, that I simply can't get rid off:

```
./input/main.cpp:18: error: 
        no matching function for call to 
        'QObject::connect(QObject*&, const char*, Input*, const char*)'
                   &input, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
                                                 ^
```

I read some previous posts on [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284936/qt-signals-and-slots-no-matching-function-for-call), double checking everything, and apparently everything looks correct. Here are the details:

./Sources/main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml/QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>
#include <QtDeclarative>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "Input.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 QApplication app(argc, argv);

 QDeclarativeView view(QUrl::fromLocalFile("input.qml"));
 QObject *item = view.rootObject();

 Input input;
 QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                  &input, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
 view.show();
 return app.exec();
}
```

./Headers/Input.h

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
class Input : public QObject
{  public:
     Input(){} // default constructor
     Q_OBJECT
   public slots:
     void cppSlot(const QString &msg) {
                  qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
          }

};
#endif // INPUT_H
```

./Input.pro

```
QT += qml quick sensors xml
QT += declarative
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    Input.cpp
RESOURCES += \
    Input.qrc
OTHER_FILES += \
    Input.qml
HEADERS += \
    Input.h
```

./Resources/Input.qrc

```
/
Input.qml
```

The connect, I am using is from the [qtproject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html) example:

```
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),&myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
```

Maybe someone could have some clue what is missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will the real `class Input` please stand up?

You seem to have one defined in Input.h, and another one in Input.cpp.  Only one of them is a Q_OBJECT and QObject subclass.  main.cpp is seeing the other one from Input.h, so it's entirely unsurprising it can't connect it.

See e.g this [tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/) for how to correctly split c++ class declarations and definitions between header and source files, if you're unfamiliar with this area of C++.

Comment: thanks. I commented out the whole Imput.h, and moved evertyhing into Input.cpp. Then the compiler gives: ./Input.cpp:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
              qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
                     ^

Comment: @timday means `#include <QDebug>` rather than `#include <QtDebug>`. ;-)

Comment: @timday. I just updated the files Input.h and Input.cpp - have a look. Then the compiler complains: ./Input.cpp:5: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'
              qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;

Comment: now... it gives: "./Input.h:6: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for Input'"

Comment: You are either missing Q_OBJECT and/or missing the `#include "Input.moc"` include at the end of your source file... or, you are missing the Input.h added to the `HEADERS` variable. Also, you do not need to include qdebug in the header since it is not used in there.

Comment: @LaszloPapp. Thanks. I remake the project to be sure that the Input.h is added to Headers. Also, I renamed all to capital letters "Input". The error still holds.

Comment: @timday. Well noticed. Thank for pointing that man! Now I solved the class double declaration as updated in my post. Only the error still remains.

Comment: @GerryWoodberg: your code is still wrong. Also, if you use QtCreator, make qmake is re-run explicitly.